# Java Applet or Unity3D for Cross-Platform 3D Surveying App

Tags: java, ios, applet, unity-game-engine

**Do you think a Java Applet or Unity3D Application is the best option to make a cross-browser 3d web-app?**

I intend to make a web application that displays 3d environments that can be navigated by dragging(with a finger or mouse depending on the platform). The web app will render 3d environments of development sites including contours, water pipeline locations, buildings etc.

The application must work on Windows Desktop, Android, iOS and Windows Phone. So this is why I am tending towards a web-app as opposed to cross-platform smart phone library(like Mosync or Marmalade). The 3d environments will be navigable(by dragging around) and contain simple(not detailed) 3d objects like buildings, mountains, pipelines, etc.

One thing I know is that WebGL is out because it doesn't work on IE and has limited support on Smart Phones(am I correct to completely disregard WebGL?).

- **Will future Smart Phone browsers continue to support Java Applets?**
- **Also is it really true I can write ONE Application/Game in Unity3D and simply compile it to run on Windows Windows, Mac, Xbox 360, PlayStation 3, Wii, iPad, iPhone and Android?**
- **Would you suggest the Unity3D application path or the Unity3D Web Player path?**
- *Concerning Unity3D, there's one thing I am unsure about: do all Unity3D features work on iOS and Android?*

Comment: *"Will future Smart Phone browsers continue to support Java Applets?"*  Given my Android 2.3.4 applet does not support applets right now, I'm guessing the answer to that is 'no'.

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK, I would go for Unity3d because it has got all intuitive features to make really cross platform web based 3d applications. In this case, go for Unity3D web player path.Also, you can convert your unity3d application to flash as well that will support in all major browsers unlike WebGL.